# Social networking "party" system

Tags: mathematics, strategy, no-computers

A **party** is a *group chat*, the only difference being there's a "**leader**" (*this is the person who started the chat*)

In these parties, there can only be **5 maximum users**, *this includes the leader*.

In addition to that, you may only be the leader of a **single party** at any given moment in time. *You can be a member of as many parties which invite you.*

Now, if there were $n$ users on this site, and they equally spread out into as **many parties as they could** (*e.g. Every user was in 5 parties*), how many parties would coexist on the site at that moment?

Comment: $n$ parties, with each user being the leader of one party?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would just be $n$ parties. Every party has five members, every person is in five parties. $5n/5=n$.